# OpenMP blocking call in thread

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, blocking

I'm already using OpenMP for some parallel processing and would like to add a control thread with a blocking receive. Most of the time this thread will be blocked and therefore I don't want it sitting there taking up a core. Ideally the blocking call would trigger a yield to an extra worker thread. How will OpenMP deal with the blocking call?

Something like this:

```
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
int cores = omp_get_num_procs();
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(cores + 1) 
    if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0) {
        send();
        blockingReceive();
    }
    else
    {
        work();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a question about OpenMP, or, certainly not about the standard. In general it is very unlikely that the OpenMP implementation is aware that the thread executing the `blockingReceive()` has blocked, since it cannot easily discover that it can block at compile time, and can't see it at run-time either unless it intercepts all system calls.

Instead, this is a question about how the operating system schedules threads when there are more threads than logicalCPUs (oversubscription). If we assume that your `blockingReceive()` turns into a blocking `read()` system call, then the OS knows that the thread is idle, and should schedule another thread onto that logicalCPU, which is what you wanted.

Comment: I think I understand now, I was confused when reading about OpenMP tasks, as they were stated specifically to react to scheduler events I thought that other constructs may not. But it looks like tasks use another scheduler built on top of the OS. Does this seem right?

Comment: Yes, more or less. OpenMP tasks are a way to distribute work to the threads that OpenMP controls, so they can migrate to OpenMP threads that would otherwise have no OpenMP work to perform (normally threads that are waiting at a barrier of some sort). That is all happening without having more OpenMP threads than logicalCPUs, and without any interaction with the operating system scheduler.